# Using the subfolder module to extend domain access

Tags: 7, domain-access

I'm using the domain access module to create multiple sites based on unique subdomains.

For instance we have a subdomain1.url.com link to one front page and subdomain2.url.com linking to another.

I need however to be able to create multiple sites under one subdomain as well.
Not only do I need unique sites for subdomain1.url.com but I also need subsites such as subdomain1.url.com/subfolder1 and subdomain1.url.com/subfolder2

To attempt this I have used the Subfolders Domain Module. Viewable here https://www.drupal.org/project/subfolders_domain

I'm able to successfully create these subfolder domains however when attempting to access them I receive a 'File not found error' I've also tried creating basic pages and pointing it to the page but I still receive the same error.

I understand there are ways to accomplish this using .htaccess and such but I'd like to continue to use the domain access module since we are taking advantage of that to limit user privileges and content to specific domains.

Are there common issues that result in the 'File not found' error I found or is there another solution?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions at http://cgit.drupalcode.org/subfolders_domain/tree/README.txt prior to installing this module?

Comment: I've attempted this but I get a 'Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the drupal database. When I run 'drush cron'